# IIS PHP create file on remote windows machine

Tags: windows, iis, permissions

I am running a php script on IIS server and trying to create files in a folders.

Basically, everything works fine just as long as the file path is on same server. However, if i change the path to another server then the following message appears:

> Warning: fopen ...   failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...

I understand that a problem lies in the permissions setting on the remote machine, but even when I grant full access for everyone on the remote server the problems persist.

I suspect that the issue is related to a permission setting in IIS, because I need to run a script as another user.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please restart the IIS on  remote server and try again.

Comment: IIS is not remote. Another server is remote

Comment: Restart that server, that you have given the file permissions.

Comment: Nothing. Also i had full control access before restart but it wont work from IIS side

Answer (score 0):

IIS Application pool identity user may not have permission to access remote system.

Run->Inetmgr->Application Pool->Select the application pool (application which is configured with this pool & showing problem)->Advanced Settings (IIS 7.0 & above)->Identity (see the user) & provide permission to access remote system to this user.

Comment: I tried. I change Identity to Custom account and put domain account credentials. but nothing

Comment: Please provide appropriate permission to Custom Account for accessing remote system.

Comment: @This account is domain account also remote folder has everyone full control

Comment: It may require a DNS flush in your remote system, the mapping of name to number can change from time to time.

Comment: @Klapsius Can you post the IIS log for when the PHP command runs. You should be seeing a specific 400 code.

Comment: i can't seen anything 2016-11-25 10:42:07 00.00.00.00 GET /my-website/ - 80 - 111.222.333.444 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 401 2 5 156
2016-11-25 10:42:08 00.00.00.00 GET /my-website/ - 80 DOMAIN\username 111.222.333.444 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 200 0 0 1359